# DDD and heavy infrastructure based 'domains' - does DDD fail here?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

My company's rarely developing stuff like fancy web shops, financial systems, request/result APIs... instead, for many of the applications we don't even need to store data at our side, thus don't need repositories, entities. What we're mostly doing is creating management systems for network devices, facilities. This means:

- The whole 'domain' is infrastructure based, with hundreds of synchronous, stateful protocols
- Most of the functionality our systems provide are written inside plugins where configuration, data and methods are tightly coupled
- Even if it's bad practice, for our stuff we often need configuration over convention

Now I'm wondering - is DDD applicable here? Does it make sense to separate the business logic from the infrastructure layer when the business layer is the infrastructure layer? Do you have any experiences with such scenarios? How is it possible to leverage certain e.g. infrastructure concerns into the domain?

**Edit**

I apologize if I was unclear with my statement "*when the business logic is the infrastructure layer*". I am well aware of the purpose and boundaries of both layers in DDD, but see this example:

A client wants you to write a SNMP device management software. He doesn't really care about SNMP itself since he may not even understand the protocol, but he does care about the "device management" part, which can be considered as the 'domain'. Now, SNMP is a binary-data, TCP/IP based protocol and somewhat complex. If you are going to write a client implementation by yourself, you probably won't be done within the next few weeks. So, what do you do? You use a framework, a library which contains all the fancy magic to get you started quickly.

Now, SNMP is a very 'dynamic' protocol. You don't know what you really get when you ask a device for its configuration. But you would like to store this configuration into a database (using your repositories) because the client asked you to do so. So you create like a dozen value objects, classes etc. to represent what a device can have. But what about the SNMP library? Well, it ships with it's own classes for every possible type a SNMP device can offer. And since the domain should never be coupled to the infrastructure layer, you are left with spending your day creating mappers from your domain entities to the SNMP classes.

Well, fine. Once you're done, the client has another request: He want's to get a Email if a device isn't reachable anymore. So you create your email-sender-service, write some business logic that fetches the email of the client from a configuration file.. when what happens? Of course, when the device isn't reachable - something you only detect on the infrastructure layer. Hence, you need to find a way to notify the domain layer about an event on the infrastructure layer, e.g. using a event bus. So again, you need to introduce a concept from the infrastructure layer in your domain layer: A "DeviceNotReachableEvent", something that is already there in the SNMP library..

You see where this is going? For every concern of the infrastructure layer, you have to create a pendant in the domain layer because your domain is something that bases on 'outer' infrastructure. Of course what happens on the network is a domain requirement, but there wouldn't be any need of doing the same stuff nearly twice without DDD.

Comment: Remember that the most important aspects of DDD aren't the tactical patterns.

Comment: So, did you ever manage to figure it out? :) 
I'm also struggling with logic that heavily depends on side effects and infrastructure layer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it make sense to separate the business logic from the infrastructure layer when the business logic is the infrastructure layer?

No necessarily.  But let's talk about this some more...

You may be confusing what an infrastructural concern is.  **In DDD, infrastructure is essentially all the code that has to interface with technical dependencies in order to drive your software.**  This would include things like databases, APIs, file systems, network concerns, etc.

But isn't your domain actually a network concern? Not necessarily.  Your domain may have all networking-related aggregates and services, but this might be very different to the actual networking infrastructural concerns that might power a system.

**Where is your competitive advantage?**

One way to determine whether DDD is right for you is to determine where your software's [competitive advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_advantage) resides.

Let's say you are developing management software for network devices.  Your domain could consist of entities which represent nodes on a network.  These may be really important things for a business utilising your software.  They want to manage the nodes at a very high level (security, grouping, allocation, etc).  The infrastructural "component" that determines and returns these node entities will likely have to implement some pretty heavy networking code to traverse through the network.  There may be a lot of connection resilience and retry code, protocols handshakes, security, etc - these are all the things that would be involved to find these nodes.  The business user doesn't care about all this stuff - it is not important to the domain HOW it's actually done, as long as those entities are available.  This is where the software has it's competitive advantage.

If the above example does not hold for you, then perhaps DDD is far from ideal.  Is it the "management of nodes" that separates your software from the rest?  Is it the "management of nodes" that sells your application?

Or is it the actual network protocol handshake algorithm that is your advantage? (I'm making up networking terms here!).  In this case, your "domain" depends upon a specific technical concern.  This would not be a candidate for DDD.

PS:  I know nothing about it, so please excuse my attempt at networking jargon!

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for your explanations. I apologize I was a little unclear with my issue, so I hope you don't mind looking at the example I wrote in the edit above. This might clarify some things.

Answer (score 1):

DDD is for all kinds of applications where the domain is complex. i.e. there are a lot of business rules which defines how objects must work and how they relate to each other. It doesn't matter if your application is used to administer infrastructure components or not.

You can say that CRUD applications are at one end of the spectra and DDD in the other. That is, DDD is a very bad fit if your application just shows forms where the users can enter whatever they like. If we simplify a bit, if you application is [task based](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) then you can probably use DDD.